# Twitter tells me Error no card found (card error)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am trying to add twitter cards to a gatsby site but when I try to see if they are valid it tells me "error no card found (card error)". Yet the twitter tag: card is there!

```js
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: 'xxx',
    description: 'xxx',
    keywords:'xxx',
    author: 'xxx',
    twitter_card: 'summary_large_image',
    twitter_creator: '@xxx',
    twitter_site: '@xxx',
    og_title: 'xxx',
    og_image: 'https://www.example.com/',
    og_url: 'https://example.netlify.com/',
    og_type: 'website',
    og_title: 'xxx',
    og_description: 'xxx.',
    og_image: 'https://www.example.com/',
  },
  plugins: ['gatsby-plugin-react-helmet'],
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-html-attributes',
      options: {
        lang: 'en',
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if adding all those twitter attributes in the `siteMetadata` is the right  way.

I know that you can implement all those open graph twitter meta attributes in a seo component. It worked in my project. See the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/add-seo-component/#seo-component). Use `react-helmet`. Look for this code snippet:

```
          <Helmet title={seo.title} titleTemplate={titleTemplate}>
            <meta name="description" content={seo.description} />
            <meta name="image" content={seo.image} />
            {seo.url && <meta property="og:url" content={seo.url} />}
            {(article ? true : null) && (
              <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
            )}
            {seo.title && <meta property="og:title" content={seo.title} />}
            {seo.description && (
              <meta property="og:description" content={seo.description} />
            )}
            {seo.image && <meta property="og:image" content={seo.image} />}
            <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
            {twitterUsername && (
              <meta name="twitter:creator" content={twitterUsername} />
            )}
            {seo.title && <meta name="twitter:title" content={seo.title} />}
            {seo.description && (
              <meta name="twitter:description" content={seo.description} />
            )}
            {seo.image && <meta name="twitter:image" content={seo.image} />}
          </Helmet>
        </>
```

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do now, only I don't know how to implement it with graphql:(